# MySQL substring_index for commas

Tags: mysql

I have a value like so:

```
43.3795, -80.4368, 3, -70,-150
```

What I am trying to do is separate the first two parts of the value so I get 43.3795 as one value and -80.4368 as the other.

I was able to get the first part I want by doing this:

```
substring_index(mapLocation, ',', 1) as 'Latitude'
```

and I tried this to get the second part:

```
substring_index(substring_index(mapLocation, ',', -2), ',',1) as 'Longitude'
```

but this returns just `-80`

How do I get the full item `-80.4368` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't what SQL is for, but just for fun...

```
SET @s = "43.3795, -80.4368, 3, -70,-150";

SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@s,',',i),',',-1)+0 x FROM ints i;
+----------+
| x        |
+----------+
|        0 |
|  43.3795 |
| -80.4368 |
|        3 |
|      -70 |
|     -150 |
|     -150 |
|     -150 |
|     -150 |
|     -150 |
+----------+
```